# AWS ELB: How can I see how many bytes of outbound network traffic an SSL-enabled ELB generates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, billing

I'm curious to know how much total outbound bytes an ELB generates.  As far as I can tell, this will be something like

(size of http responses) + (size of SSL handshake transactions)

I can calculate the former by looking at my web server logs.  However, I'm having a hard time getting to the number of bytes sent out while handling TLS handshakes.  Does AWS provide this metric anywhere?

Details: I'm using a 'classic' ELB and all the request I handle are SSL requests.

Comment: AWS has cloud watch service where you can view the metrics and logs if configured at detail level. But cloud watch metrics at ELB level has lot of metrics I believe you will get this info from there

Comment: ELB metrics does not include outgoing bytes

Comment: the network at the ELB level should include that, right ?

Comment: Yep, VPC Flow logs might help here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html

Comment: Someone who was access to the billing CSV that AWS generates was able to get the amount of outgoing network traffic caused by the ELB.  It seems billing is the only place to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handshake of a TLS connection is pretty much constant and do not depend on your application.  So your function is really : `number of connections * ( size of http responses + constant)`

Here is a good article that estimates the payload to average ~6.5k  (depending on your certificate size) : http://netsekure.org/2010/03/tls-overhead/

The list of ELB metrics is available here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html 
This web page has also some good details about how to migrate from ELB to ALB and estimate your cost.

ALB has that metric exposed `EstimatedProcessedBytes`

Depending on your application, the TLS handshake overhead will be negligible compared to the amount of byte going out of your app.  Unless you have an app with many short lived connections to exchange just a few bytes.  IN that case, a refactoring of the app might help to save on outgoing bandwidth costs.

Comment: I was about to comment that 'I don't think this is right, because if TLS session resumption is enabled on the server then the amount of data transferred will depend on how many sessions are resumed (because then the certificate is not transferred).  Then I saw that ELB does not support TLS session resumption -- what a waste!

Comment: you're correct.  New sessions cost ~6.5k.  Sessions resume costs ~330 bytes.  I was thinking more about your question and I wonder if VPC Flow Logs would help you to capture the total amount of traffic, provided that the ELB is the only service in your subnet.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html